# Spring boot to accepts cXML?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxml

I am attempting to write a service to accept punch out data and am required to accept the data as [cXML](http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLUsersGuide.pdf). I attempted to generate some models via the psd and bind that to misprint boot app. However, it does not unmarshall the data:

> Failed to read HTTP message: 
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could  not unmarshal to [class com.a.internet.models.CXML]: null;
>   nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

I'm hoping I could fiddle with the binding but am unfamiliar with cXML or how to tweak this to accepts it. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.